# Symmetric number of bins in qcut around zero

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I have a pandas dataframe with different number of integers and `NaNs` in each row. I would like to allocate values in each row into 8 bins - 4 bins for negative values and 4 bins for positive values per row. So, there will be different number of values in each bin per row. Any hints on how to adjust `qcut` function for that? Thanks!

Comment: Just to check, are you referring to a Pandas dataframe here?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Sorry for not indicating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you could just do a `qcut` on positive values and a `qcut` on negative values.

For example, given the dataframe:

```
>>> df
        vals
0  -0.456460
1   0.448368
2   0.186750
3   1.056617
4  -0.035620
5  -0.609843
6   0.126376
7   0.160817
8  -1.495441
9   0.730763
10 -0.005071
11  0.677918
12 -0.779553
13  0.717374
14  2.250258
15 -0.801028
16  0.306408
17  0.538970
18 -2.120528
19  1.066903
```

Use 2 `qcuts`, one for positive and one for negative.

```
df.loc[df.vals > 0,'bin'] = pd.qcut(df.loc[df.vals > 0,'vals'], q=4)

df.loc[df.vals < 0,'bin'] = pd.qcut(df.loc[df.vals < 0,'vals'], q=4)
```

And as a result, they are binned into 8 unique bins, 4 for positive and 4 for negative:

```
>>> df
        vals                 bin
0  -0.456460    (-0.695, -0.351]
1   0.448368      (0.276, 0.608]
2   0.186750      (0.125, 0.276]
3   1.056617       (0.812, 2.25]
4  -0.035620  (-0.351, -0.00507]
5  -0.609843    (-0.695, -0.351]
6   0.126376      (0.125, 0.276]
7   0.160817      (0.125, 0.276]
8  -1.495441    (-2.122, -0.975]
9   0.730763      (0.608, 0.812]
10 -0.005071  (-0.351, -0.00507]
11  0.677918      (0.608, 0.812]
12 -0.779553    (-0.975, -0.695]
13  0.717374      (0.608, 0.812]
14  2.250258       (0.812, 2.25]
15 -0.801028    (-0.975, -0.695]
16  0.306408      (0.276, 0.608]
17  0.538970      (0.276, 0.608]
18 -2.120528    (-2.122, -0.975]
19  1.066903       (0.812, 2.25]
```

You can sort the bins to visualize them like this, allowing you to see 4 bins for positive values and 4 bins for negative values:

```
np.sort(df['bin'].unique())

array([Interval(-2.1219999999999999, -0.97499999999999998, closed='right'),
       Interval(-0.97499999999999998, -0.69499999999999995, closed='right'),
       Interval(-0.69499999999999995, -0.35099999999999998, closed='right'),
       Interval(-0.35099999999999998, -0.0050699999999999999, closed='right'),
       Interval(0.125, 0.27600000000000002, closed='right'),
       Interval(0.27600000000000002, 0.60799999999999998, closed='right'),
       Interval(0.60799999999999998, 0.81200000000000006, closed='right'),
       Interval(0.81200000000000006, 2.25, closed='right')], dtype=object)
```

Comment: How can I do this row by row? When I try this: `quintiles_df=df.apply(lambda x: qcut(df.loc[df>0], q=4), axis=1)`, I receve an error: _raise NotImplementedError("Indexing a MultiIndex with a "NotImplementedError: ('Indexing a MultiIndex with a DataFrame key is not implemented', 'occurred at index (10, 2012-09-25 10:20:00)')_

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're trying to do. Can you post a minimal example as an edit to your question?

Answer (score 0):

In case you just want to use Integer for bins and not Categorical:

```
df.loc[df.vals > 0,'bin']= pd.qcut(df.loc[df.vals > 0,'vals'], q=4, labels=False)
df.loc[df.vals < 0,'bin']= pd.qcut(df.loc[df.vals < 0,'vals'], q=4, labels=False)-4
```

Or as a function:

```
def symmetricBins(df, numBins, column):
    df.loc[ df[column] > 0, column+'Bin'] = pd.qcut(df.loc[ df[column] > 0, column], numBins, labels=False) + 1
    df.loc[ df[column] < 0, column+'Bin'] = pd.qcut(df.loc[ df[column] < 0, column], numBins, labels=False) - numBins
```